# Automatically Insert first row soon after table is created / recreated using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I want **Username = Administrator** and **Password = admin**, soon after table is created (or whenever table is recreate).

1. Is there any way to insert first row using following code. I do not want to use a separate insert query
2. Is there any constraint in Hibernate to restrict user from deleting (first) row

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "Users")
   public class Users implements Serializable {

       @Id
       @Column(name = "Username", unique = true, nullable = false)
       private String username;

       @Column(name = "Password", nullable = false)
       private String password;

       /**************** getter & setter ************/

   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is called fixtures. With Hibernate you can supply `import.sql` file on your classpath with your initial data (insert statements).

There's a bit [more information](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Data_Services/5/html/Metadata_Repository_Reference_Guide/jdbc-storage-connector.html) on the JBoss' site.

The `import.sql` file is a simple text file with SQL statements, one line per statement:

```
insert into users (id, username) values (1, 'administrator');
insert into users (id, username) values (2, 'user');
...
```